# Is f a surjection

Tags: functions

Define
$$ f : \Bbb N×\Bbb N → \Bbb N \text{ such that } f(x,y) = 7x+3y$$
How to prove is f is a surjection ?

I'm not $100\%$ sure how to approach this, but for all $b \in B$ there is some $a \in A$ such that $f(a) = b$. So some $z \in N$ , $z= f(x)$ which is $z = 7x + 3y$ after this would I re arrange for $x$ ? Zero is considered as a Natural number

Comment: You get two different answers because your question isn't clear on whether the function takes in only natural numbers, or if it takes in any real numbers as input. You need to be consistent if you want consistent answers.

Comment: I did state it, Define f : N×N → N

Comment: And then a moment later you talk about $z\in R$. It's not strange that people are confused.

Comment: Ahh yes I see I have made the changes sorry guys

Comment: It would be helpful to clarify whether zero is considered a natural number.

Answer (score 6):

$f$ is **not** surjective since $1$ has **no** preimage. To see this is true, we have: $7x + 3y \ge 7 + 3 = 10 > 1$. Thus there is **no** pair $(x,y)$ with $f(x,y) = 1$.

Comment: How'd you figure that out ?

Comment: Because the coefficients of $x,y$ are coprime, the function extends to a surjection from $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb Z$.  Indeed the original map hits all *sufficiently large* natural numbers (one only needs to find three consecutive integers in its range).

Comment: I just don't understand why 7x+3y >= 7 + 3 = 10 > 1 like where did that come from ? I thought you just go something like f(x,y),  f(0, 0) = 0

Comment: @M.Jones: For many people, $0 \notin \mathbb{N}$. For others, $0 \in \mathbb{N}$. In any case, the smallest few images are $f(0,0) = 0$, $f(0,1) = 3$, and $f(1,0) =7$; anything else is bigger and nothing maps to 1.

Comment: @Kundor sorry for the rookie questions , but what do you mean nothing maps to 1 ?

Comment: @M.Jones: Like the answer says, there are no inputs to $f$ which result in 1.

Answer (score 1):

Given $z\in\mathbb{R}$, we seek $(x,y)$ such  that $z = 7x + 3y$. Let $x=0$ for example, and take $y=z/3$. Hence $f(0, z/3)=z$ and $f$ is surjective. At the time the map was written $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$

Comment: I'm not sure which answer to go for because @Deepsea has a opposite answer

Comment: @M.Jones You changed the question 10 minutes ago, so no wonder that some of the posted answers no longer apply.

Answer (score 1):

When $x$ is not $0$, it is true that for some $k$, $y=kx$. If this is true, then
$$f(x, y)=7x+3kx=(7+3k)x$$
Recall that $f(x, y)$ is a surjection if for every real number $a$, there are some $x$ and $y$ such that
$$f(x, y)=a$$
or
$$(7+3k)x=a$$
This is always true for some $x$, because we can just let
$$x=\frac{a}{7+3k}$$
As long as we choose $x$ and $y$ so that $k$ is not equal to $-\frac{7}{3}$.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming $f:R^2 \rightarrow R$, for a given real $z$, can we find reals $x,y$ for which $z = f(x,y)$? Hint: $x,y$ need not be unique.

Comment: As presently stated the Question asks about a surjection on the natural numbers $\mathbb N$.

Comment: @hardmath It was not when I wrote the answer!

Comment: He is correct it was my fault sorry !